# how to make optional parametres in zendframework URL

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I am new to Zend, but very very keen to learn. This is really just a quick question on routing in Zend Framework.

I understand the basic of it but I am still confused about how I can create some optional parameters at the end of my URL. For example, I have the following default page URL:

```
examplesite.com/accounts/enquiry
```

I now want to add two additional parameters to it i.e:

```
userid= 6
location= 12
```

So, the eventual URL should look like:

```
examplesite.com/accounts/enquiry/6/12
but   
examplesite.com/accounts/enquiry
```

Will get you to the same page.

I am not clear. How do it do this? I mean, this is not a bespoke URL. so, I don't need to create a custom route. It basically just the last two parameters that need to be added to the page.

How do I do this?

Comment: You do need to use a custom route, because otherwise there's no way for ZF to know that '6' is the userid, and '12' is the location; and that they're optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 2 parameters are controller and action name, the named params.
Here you are:

```
examplesite.com/accounts/enquiry/userid/6/location/12
```

or you can define your own route like this:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('accounts/enquiry/:userid/:location);
```

and then add it to router:

```
$router->addRoute('accounts', $route);
```

Comment: hi Konradwww. Thank you for your reply. However, when i add userid/6/location/12 it returns:erro, page not found.Also. i dontwant to have the userid nad location there. i just want to be able to put the numbers. i.e /6/2/ etc

Comment: so you can't use the default route. You have then define your own route. Please see my modified anser.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom route inside your `Bootstrap.php`, e.g. (untested):

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{

    [...]

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();

    $accounts = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'accounts/enquiry/:userid/:location',
            array(
                'userid' => '[0-9]{2}',
                'location' => '[0-9]{2}',
                'controller' => 'accounts', 
                'action' => 'enquiry',
            )
        );

    $router->addRoute('accounts', $accounts);

    [...]

}
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: hi simplyray. thank you so much for that. it has really clarified things for me. one question though; what does the {2} represent?

Comment: `[0-9]{2}` is some basic validation of your GET variables. `[0-9]` means only digits and `{2}` a length of 2 (exact!). just remove it if you don't need it. Think you might better just use `[0-9]` without any length specification ...

Comment: Oh and  since you're new (?) at stackoverflow: please accept this responde if it answers your initial question.

Comment: hi simplyray. thank you for your help. i indeed accpet this responce since it answers my questions fully. but i dont know how to accept it. what button do you want me to press

Comment: simply click on the icon(shape) next to my answer on the left hand (it's under the 0 and up- & downvote arrows).